# How to use SelectToken to find value in nested dynamic JSON

Tags: c#, json.net, quickbooks-online

I can't figure out how to use JToken to get the "Total Income" amount of "325.00".

I have tried quite a few different lines of code but seem to be missing something obvious.

```
{
  "Rows": {
    "Row": [
      {
        "Rows": {
        },
        "type": "Section",
        "group": "Income",
        "Summary": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "Total Income"
            },
            {
              "value": "325.00"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. I am coding in C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the specific JSON sample that you have given in your question, you can extract the `325.00` value using [`SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) like this:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var amount = (string)obj.SelectToken("Rows.Row[0].Summary.ColData[1].value");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WRMAVu

If you want to extract both the label and the amount you can use [`SelectTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) instead with a wildcard for the `ColData` index:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var values = obj.SelectTokens("Rows.Row[0].Summary.ColData[*].value")
                .Select(t => (string)t)
                .ToArray();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DHZhS2

Comment: Thanks Brian. Why is it not ("Rows.Row.Rows[0].Summary.ColData[*].value")?

Comment: Because `Summary` is not inside the innermost `Rows` object as you posted in your question; it is inside the first object in the `Row` array.  The inner `Rows` object is empty.  If your actual JSON is different from the sample you posted, then you might need to adjust the path accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again - what if the row position is different each time? Is there a way to search or query the JSON results for the token?

Comment: More specifically, if my JSON result has multiple types (“Section”) and groups (“Income”), how can I use SelectToken to get the data within a given type and group?

Comment: You will probably need to use a LINQ query to select the data in that case.  If you can edit your question (or ask a new question) to provide a better example of the JSON and what you are trying to get out of it, then I can show you how to write a LINQ query to get the data out of it.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I will post a new question.